# Band pass filter

Tags: filter, formula-derivation

What is this bandpass filter transfer function derivation?
http://imageshack.com/a/img674/9016/mKXqCQ.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There are several mehods for calculating the closed-loop gain function of an opamp with feedback. I think, for the shown circuit the most simple way is as follows:

From H. Blacks famous formula - assuming ideal opamps with an open-loop gain of infinity - we know that the closed-loop gain can be written as

**Acl=-Hf/Hr.**

with (applying the superposition rule):

**Hf** (forward function)=**Vn/Vi** if Vout=0,  and

**Hr**(return function, feedback factor)=**Vn/Vout** if Vi=0.

(Vn:voltage at the negative input terminal),

Both functions Hf and Hr can be found by applying the well-known voltage divider rule.